# Preparing image segmentation dataset

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I have 224, 224 greyscale images and 224, 224, 6 one hot encoded mask for image segmentation model. I saved the mask into npy file and organised the data as below.

```
data/
...images/
......img_1.png
......img_2.png
...masks/
......img_1.npy
......img_2.npy
```

The problem I am facing is that npy file is not very well supported in tensorflow. The below is my attempt, but the dataset seemed to be flawed to train a model.

```
# Define paths
image_path = Path('/path/to/images')
mask_path = Path('/path/to/masks')

# List files in the images directory
image_files = [str(f) for f in image_path.iterdir()]
mask_files = [str(mask_path / (f.stem + ".npy")) for f in image_path.iterdir()]

# Split the dataset
split_ratio = (0.8, 0.1, 0.1)
train_files, test_files, train_masks, test_masks = train_test_split(image_files, mask_files, test_size=split_ratio[2], random_state=42)
train_files, val_files, train_masks, val_masks = train_test_split(train_files, train_masks, test_size=split_ratio[1]/(1-split_ratio[2]), random_state=42)

def process_path(image_filepath, mask_filepath):
    # Load and process the image
    image = tf.io.read_file(image_filepath)
    image = tf.image.decode_png(image, channels=1)  # Adjust channels according to your images
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)

    # Load and process the mask
    mask = tf.numpy_function(load_npy, [mask_filepath], tf.float32)
    return image, mask

def load_npy(mask):
    mask = np.load(mask)
    return mask.astype(np.float32)

batch_size = 32
# Convert lists to TensorFlow datasets
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_files, train_masks))
val_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((val_files, val_masks))
test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_files, test_masks))

# Preprocess the data
train_ds = train_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
test_ds = test_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

# Shuffle, batch, and cache the training dataset
train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(train_files)).batch(batch_size).cache().prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

# Batch the validation and test datasets
val_ds = val_ds.batch(batch_size).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
test_ds = test_ds.batch(batch_size).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

How should I correctly establish a dataset for multi-class segmentation using one hot encoding? Maybe I should have not stored the mask into npy in the first place?